# Perl CLI in-place string substitution/replacement of multiple lines with special characters

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I’m trying to write a CLI command to change the contents of a config file.

The config file has these lines:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

I want to change those two lines to this one line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

I want to replace multiple lines, so I’m trying to use Perl to do that.

```
perl -i -pe 's/JAVA_OPTS="\$JAVA_OPTS -XX:\+UseParNewGC"\nJAVA_OPTS="\$JAVA_OPTS -XX:\+UseConcMarkSweepGC"/JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"/' name-of-file.sh
```

However, this command doesn’t change the file.  I’m guessing the regular expression doesn’t match.  I don’t know why.  I’ve tried several variations of the command and I’ve tried escaping and double-escaping the `$` and `+` symbols in the match string, but nothing I do makes a difference.  Can someone please offer a solution?

I’m using Bash 3.2.57(1) and Perl 5.18.4 on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this perl command line with `-0777` and `\R` instead of `\n`. `-0777` enabled slurp mode in perl to match across multiple lines and `\R` lets it match all kind of line breaks (including DOS or OSX or Unix line breaks):

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/JAVA_OPTS="\$JAVA_OPTS -XX:\+UseParNewGC"\nJAVA_OPTS="\$JAVA_OPTS -XX:\+UseConcMarkSweepGC"/JAVA_OPTS="\$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"/' file
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much!  I also needed to update the replacement string to escape the `$` there as well, otherwise “$JAVA_OPTS” was omitted.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I missed out that.

Comment: Yes I am also on OSX only but I do get `\r` sometimes in text files from external sources